# How to pass a matrix as a list of vectors in a cartesian product in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, combinatorics

I'm trying to create a combinatorics matrix from a series of vectors. If I wanted all vectors to be included in the combination I would use:

```
CombinatoricsMatrix = list(itertools.product(vector1, vector2, ...)
```

or

```
CombinatoricsMatrix  = cartesian((vector1, vector2))
```

such that if

```
vector1 = [a]
vector2 = [1,2]
CombinatoricsMatrix  = cartesian((vector1, vector2))
CombinatoricsMatrix = [a,1; a,2]
```

However, there are some matrices that I want to pass as 'a list of vectors' so that the elements of those vectors are not included in the combination.

For example if

```
matrix3 = [w,x; y,z]
```

the desired output is

```
CombinatoricsMatrix  = cartesian((vector1, vector2, matrix3 ))
CombinatoricsMatrix = [a,1,[w,x]; a,1,[y,z]; a,2,[w,x]; a,2,[y,z]]
```

Any ideas? Note that the length and amount of vectors were kept short for the example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are likely more pythonic ways to do this but one solution is to zip the matrices such that

```
CombinatoricsMatrix  = list(itertools.product(vector1, vector2, zip(matrix3))
```